# Build Job with link to commit (not branch)

Tags: jenkins

I have the following code in my `Jenkinsfile`:

`build job: 'project_1', propagate: false, wait: false`

Which builds a separate project, which works great. However, I would like a link to the particular job. Unfortunately, it just links to the branch where it is building in `master`

```
[Pipeline] build (Building project_1)
Scheduling project: project_1 » master (link is here)
```

I believe when I set `propagate: true, wait: true` it would link to the job, but I cannot do this due to constraints in the project. Is there a way around this to get a link to the particular job without setting propagate or wait to true?

Comment: Is your project_1 a multibranch pipeline ?

Comment: See this jenkins issue https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-38339 and the comment from Werner Wessely.